# Como cargar un Select con AngularJS y JSON

Tags: html5, angularjs, json

Buenas, estoy intentando cargar un select con AngularJS llamando a un Json pero no sé muy bien como hacerlo

Tengo este JSON

```
       angular.module('playersApp', []).controller("AllPlayerssCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.players = [
    {
        "player": {
          "info": {
            "position": "D",
            "shirtNum": 4,
            "positionInfo": "Centre/Right Central Defender"
          },
          "nationalTeam": {
            "isoCode": "BE",
            "country": "Belgium",
            "demonym": "Belgian"
          },
          "age": "27 years 139 days",
          "name": {
            "first": "Toby",
            "last": "Alderweireld"
          },
          "id": 4916,
          "currentTeam": {
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "teamType": "FIRST",
            "shortName": "Spurs",
            "id": 21
          }
        },
        "stats": [
          {
            "name": "goals",
            "value": 5
          },
          {
            "name": "losses",
            "value": 20
          },
          {
            "name": "wins",
            "value": 48
          },
          {
            "name": "draws",
            "value": 23
          },
          {
            "name": "fwd_pass",
            "value": 1533
          },
          {
            "name": "goal_assist",
            "value": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "appearances",
            "value": 80
          },
          {
            "name": "mins_played",
            "value": 6953
          },
          {
            "name": "backward_pass",
            "value": 308
          }
        ]
      },...];
```

y estoy intentando cargar un select en el HTML intentando cargar el value del option con el id y que se muestre el nombre completo del jugador

HTML

```
<select id="select-players" ng-model="Jugador" ng-options="jugadores as jugadores.player.name.first jugadores.player.name.last for jugadores in players track by jugadores.id" >
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <select id="select-players" ng-model="Jugador" ng-options="jugador as (jugador.player.name.first + ' ' + jugador.player.name.last) for jugador in players track by jugador.player.id ">
> ```

```js
function MyController($scope) {
$scope.players = [
    {
        "player": {
          "info": {
            "position": "D",
            "shirtNum": 4,
            "positionInfo": "Centre/Right Central Defender"
          },
          "nationalTeam": {
            "isoCode": "BE",
            "country": "Belgium",
            "demonym": "Belgian"
          },
          "age": "27 years 139 days",
          "name": {
            "first": "Toby",
            "last": "Alderweireld"
          },
          "id": 4916,
          "currentTeam": {
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "teamType": "FIRST",
            "shortName": "Spurs",
            "id": 21
          }
        },
        "stats": [
          {
            "name": "goals",
            "value": 5
          },
          {
            "name": "losses",
            "value": 20
          },
          {
            "name": "wins",
            "value": 48
          },
          {
            "name": "draws",
            "value": 23
          },
          {
            "name": "fwd_pass",
            "value": 1533
          },
          {
            "name": "goal_assist",
            "value": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "appearances",
            "value": 80
          },
          {
            "name": "mins_played",
            "value": 6953
          },
          {
            "name": "backward_pass",
            "value": 308
          }
        ]
      }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">

<select id="select-players" ng-model="Jugador" ng-options="jugador as (jugador.player.name.first + ' ' + jugador.player.name.last) for jugador in players track by jugador.player.id " >
   
</select>
   
</div>
```

Si quieres concatenar el nombre tienes que usar

> ```
> (jugador.player.name.first + ' ' + jugador.player.name.last)
> ```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, me faltó la concatenación y por eso no me cargaba el select